# Difference between "x-gzip" and "gzip" for content-encoding

Tags: networking, encoding, http-compression

In request header, we have `accept-encoding: gzip`, but got response with encoding `x-gzip`.

I found [this note about x-gzip and gzip](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5):

> Use of program names for the identification of encoding formats
>   is not desirable and is discouraged for future encodings. Their
>   use here is representative of historical practice, not good
>   design. For compatibility with previous implementations of HTTP,
>   applications SHOULD consider "x-gzip" and "x-compress" to be
>   equivalent to "gzip" and "compress" respectively.

Does it mean `x-gzip` is equal to `gzip`? We can simply use the same way to unzip `x-gzip` content as `gzip` content?

Answer (score 12):

`x-gzip` and `gzip` are equivalent.

The content you receive can be unzipped the same way for both.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should use `gzip` instead of `x-gzip` because `x-` means eXperimental and `x-gzip` remains for historical reasons.

ref: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6648#appendix-B